# Find $B$ if $B=A-{{1}\over{2}} A^2+{{1}\over{3}} A^3 -{{1}\over{4}} A^4+...$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $$
> \ A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\ 0 & 0 & a & a^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
> $$ and
>   $B=A-{{1}\over{2}} A^2+{{1}\over{3}} A^3 -{{1}\over{4}} A^4+...$
>
> $i)$ Find the matrix $B$
>
> $ii)$ Prove that $A=B+ {{1}\over{2!}} B^2+ {{1}\over{3!}} B^3+...$

My attempt:

$i)$
I calculated $A^2$ by multiplying $A$ by itself, then foundnd $A^3$ by multiplying $A$ by $A^2$, ans so on.

Then I noted that $A^n=0$ for $n\geq 4$

$A^2= A.A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & a^2 & 2a^3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

$A^3= A^2.A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & a^3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

$A^4=A^3.A =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

$A^n=0$ for every $n\geq 4$, so:

$B= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & {{1}\over{2}} a^2 & {{1}\over {3}}a^3 \\ 0 & 0 & a & {{1}\over{2}} a^2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$

But is there any way easier than my way ?

And what about $(ii)$ ?

Comment: It's a shame that A & B are matrices. I'm tempted to provide this fake proof: Clearly $\log(1+A)=A-\frac{1}{2}A^2+\frac{1}{3} A^3 - \frac{1}{4} A^4 + \dots = B.$ Then $A=e^B - 1 = B + \frac{1}{2!} B^2 + \frac{1}{3!} B^3 + \dots$ as desired.

Comment: @Displayname  if I remember correctly,  the same idea works for matrices...

Comment: Not sure if this helps: You can anticipate that $A^4=0$ since $A$ has characteristic equation $\lambda^4=0$.

Comment: there is a problem with the signs here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B=\ln(I+A)$, and so $e^B=I+A\implies ii)$...

You asked if there was a better way of doing it...  I believe the answer is to notice that you have the power series for $\ln$ and $\exp$ respectively;   and then use the fact (probably covered in your course) that those series can be applied to matrices.  See [for instance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Definition) .

Comment: This may be a bit cryptic but it's actually correct.

Comment: I do not think the OP is able to satisfy the condition $||A||<1$.

Comment: By choosing $a$ small, we get $\mid\mid I+A-I\mid\mid =\mid\mid A\mid\mid\lt\epsilon $.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. For (ii), just compute $B^2$, $B^3$, $B^4$, and observe that $B^4 = O$. Afterwards, verify that
$$A = B + \frac{1}{2!}B^2 + \frac{1}{3!} B^3.$$

> For your information,
>  $$B^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & a^2 & a^3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a^2 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$ and
> $$B^3 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & a^3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$